# Examples and Documentation for Apache Deltaspike - where are they?

Tags: java-ee-6, cdi

I followed the path of Java EE for quite a while now, used JBoss Seam and followed its standardization within CDI.

Now after trying to solve the first steps on the hard path from Seam 2 to 3 migration, I learned that all was moved to [Apache Deltaspike](http://incubator.apache.org/deltaspike/index.html).

But while Seam was decently documented and equipped with examples, Deltaspike is not. There are menu items leading to "Documentation", which is very poor, littered with TODOs and without any visible structure and to "Examples", which is more or less a joke.

Ever since I tried to step up to Java EE 6, I feel a bit like standing in the rain - even though it's great, that many concepts of Seam 2 went into the standard, I miss many things I had before - and exactly those things should be covered by CDI extensions. Here again, it's great that there is a common effort to channel those extensions in a project like Apache Deltaspike - but at the moment there is a very high hurdle to get benefits from it, even if you're not a beginner in the technology.

So - can anyone lead me to decent resources, documentation and examples how to use and understand the CDI extensions?

Comment: FYI, I wondered about the same thing. The official Deltaspike website looks like a deserted and empty wasteland.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, the documentation isn't the best. We certainly welcome contributions for it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in other responses, the DeltaSpike documentation is a little lacking. You could always take a look at the tests and javadoc. For examples, I think you'll find [JBoss jdf quickstarts](http://www.jboss.org/jdf/quickstarts/get-started/) to be the best location for examples currently. Do a search on the right for DeltaSpike and you should see around seven examples.

Comment: +1
Arjan: You could help them. Apache folks are usually very friendly.

Comment: Thanx, it's a start, but I do hope the "official" page will be improved, especially to get less experienced developers quickly on track.

Comment: We're working on it. It'll take some time though, good documentation isn't written over night.

Answer (score 1):

DeltaSpike is still early in its development. It is only at version 0.3; it might be quite some time before it's production-ready. Until then, you might take a look at [MyFaces CODI](http://myfaces.apache.org/extensions/cdi/) or [Seam](http://www.seamframework.org/Seam3), two projects whose development has halted as they are presently being merged into DeltaSpike.

The documentation at the DeltaSpike web site, I agree, is quite insufficient for users; I bet it's just for people that want to test it out or develop for it.

Comment: I agree, but on the Seam page RedHat is telling us, that development for it was halted, so it does not make sense to use it any longer - but if I have to wait for the new project to become stable - what should I use in my projects in the meantime?

Comment: There are quite a few projects already using DeltaSpike in production. The code is actually quite mature as it's a mix of CODI and Seam 3 code, which were both already production worthy.

Comment: @LightGuard Oh, I had no idea it was being used. I guess it stands to reason it would be quick-to-production.

Comment: I'd like to get the biggest bang for the time with the documentation. What do you feel would be best for some rather quick additions to the current documentation? I'm a little too close to the project :) to know where we're lacking for a first time user.

Comment: @LightGuard Hmm, I wish I could offer more constructive criticism, but I'm not close enough to the project to know what it needs :) Maybe I was wrong to criticize it for lack of documentation; if so, I apologize. I think the comprehensive guides offered by JBoss for the Seam modules and Weld ([example](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.5.Final/en-US/html/)) are really excellent, though. Maybe DeltaSpike could imitate that style of documentation, if you think that's a sensible way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a concrete example.  I am a reasonably experienced software person.  I would like to use DeltaSpike `BeanProvider.getContextReference` to inject an EJB into some code that is not itself an EJB.  I included the requisite Maven dependencies and added the BeanProvider.getContextReference code to one of my classes.  I'm getting error messages that tell me that DeltaSpike is not configured.  Two hours with the documentation did not get me any closer to understanding what I need to do simply to turn it on.  What seems to be missing is a "How to configure DeltaSpike core." page.

Comment: There is no config needed. Your CDI container is just not ready at the point you try to call the method.